# I can not display binding value of a custom control's property when control loads

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a custom control in my wpf application.  It is a custom "auto-complete" `TextBox` that users can type text into and get an updating list of options based on their input.

The control template is as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AutoCompleteTextBox}">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="PART_ControlBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
             <Grid>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                 <Button x:Name="PART_DropDownButton" Grid.Column="1"  />
             </Grid>
         </Border>
         <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" StaysOpen="False" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
             <ListBox x:Name="PART_ListBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single"/>
         </Popup>
     </Grid>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

basically users type into the `TextBox` and a `Popup` displays a `ListBox` with options.  When the user selects an option from the `ListBox` the custom control code fills the `TextBox` with a property from one of the `ListBox` selecteditem's fields. (this field's name is supplied as a string type `DependencyProperty`)

The `SelectedItem` `DependencyProperty` that I bind to is declared as follows

```
Public Property SelectedItem As Object
    Get
        Return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
Public Shared ReadOnly SelectedItemProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
                    "SelectedItem", GetType(Object), GetType(AutoCompleteTextBox), _
                    New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault))
```

## PROBLEM

When the `SelectedItem` property of the control is already bound when it is created/rendered, I need to fill the TextBox with the "name" of the `SelectedItem`(not only when the `ListBox` selection changes, which is what I have now).

## What I Tried

I tried to access this `SelectedItem`in the `EndInit` and `OnInitialize` event of the base custom control but it has a value of nothing.   I can't use the loaded event because it does not allow me to ovverride it.

Can someone help me figure out what event to use for when the control is first loaded.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where are you trying to bind `SelectedItem` a `TextBox`? Where is this `TextBox`, in the template I did not notice it. Or do you just need the value of `SelectedItem` in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding SelectedItem property to `ControlTemplate`

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
              Content={TemplateBinding SelectedItem}
              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```